# Python: how to create subdirectory with each have the same file at the same time?

Tags: python, file

```
import os

# Main working path
os.chdir(r"C:\Python DSA\LeetCode")

main_path = r"C:\Python DSA\LeetCode"
leetcode_subdir_path = []
leetcode_note = []

# 
for i in range(3, 8):
    leetcode_subdir_path.append(f"Leetcode.00{i}")
    leetcode_note.append(f"Leetcode00{i}.md")
#print(leetcode_subdir_path)

for folder_name in leetcode_subdir_path:
    temp_folder_path = os.path.join(main_path,folder_name)
    # os.mkdir(temp_folder_path)

    subdirectories = os.mkdir(temp_folder_path)
    with open (file="temp.md", mode="w+") as file:
        file.write('Hello world')


 main
     |_folder001
             
     |_folder002
             
     |_folder003
             
     |_folder004
     |_MD.md
```

I want to create folders within range from 2 to 50 under a main folder, and each of the sub-folder containing an MD according to their folder id, but after running the code,sub-folders have been created,but there is only 1 temp.md created, and it located as below,

```
main
     |_folder001
             |_001.md
     |_folder002
             |_002.md
     |_folder003
             |_003.md
     |_folder004
             |_004.md
    ----------
```

**Questions:**

1. how to rewrite the codes above so that each sub-folder containing an MD file, instead of parallel to the sub-folder?
2. how can I rewrite the code so that the names of the MD file created has the same number as their located folder? e.g.:

   ```
    folder name:leetcode011 ==> MD name: leetcode011.md
   ```

Comment: `with open (file=os.path.join(temp_folder_path, folder_name + ".md"), mode="w+") as file:`?